# ROUND and WORKSHEETFUNCTION.ROUND

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

Why are the resulting A1 (0.224) and B1 (0.224000006914139) different?

```
Sub a()
Cells(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Rnd(-1), 4)
Cells(1, 2) = Round(Rnd(-1), 4)
Cells(1, 3) = "=a1=b1"
Cells(1, 4) = "'0.2240"
End Sub
```

And how can one copy B1 and paste to D1 with four decimal places without losing the trailing zero? Can I alter the last `"'0.2240"` by something with `rnd(-1)` or `cells(1,2)`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that `Rnd` returns a datatype `Single`. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009008)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

When `Round` is passed `numdecimalplaces`> 0 and a `Single` value, it honors that data type, and returns a `Single`. `WorksheetFunction.Round` does not: it returns a double.  (If `Round` is passed a `Double`, it returns a `Double`)

This does not matter *within VBA itself* (see image of Watch Window below for evidence)

The issue occurs when the values are placed in Excel Cells, and the are converted to Excel's cell data type.  The conversion of `Single` incurs Floating point precision issues

To fix this, your code could be

```
Cells(1, 2) = Round(CDbl(Rnd(-1)), 4)
```

[image]

To place the result in `Cell(1, 4)` **as text** you can use

```
Cells(1, 4) = "'" & Format(Cells(1, 2), "0.0000")
```

or

```
Cells(1, 4) = "'" & Cells(1, 2).Text
```

Note: the `"'" &` is necassary because Excel recognises the string as a number, and "helpfully" converts it back to number

Comment: As a newbie, I didn't know (1) if `rnd(-1)` is a single, (2) the way `round` handles a single and a double, (3) how to use `cdbl`, and (4) whether `worksheetfunction` alone is enough. Much appreciate this laborious answer.

Comment: @JunyongKim Happy to help.  FYI, you can change the accepted answer if you want to (no pressure...)

Comment: Ahh, right. My bad. I stand corrected. Thought it must have been the same issue but this make sense! I can't delete my answer untill OP marks this as answered I'm afraid. + (Btw, the second part of the question doesn't need the apostrophe per se. Format does the trick (for me) while your second option does not work I'm afraid. Op just wanted to have the trailing zero.)

Comment: @Jdv re the `"'" &` the OP said (in a comment) _but I need not formats but strings._ For me using `Cells(1, 4) = Format(Cells(1, 2), "0.0000")` Excel converts back to a number - unless you pre-format the cell as Text (sure it _displays_ with trailing `0`'s, but it's a number, not a string).  And `"'" & Cells(1, 2).Text` _does_ work for me.  Maybe we have some regional settings differences?

Comment: For me the `Format` function does exactly as explained [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php) and returns a string. Im on a Dutch version of excel 2019 and 2010. Both worked fine and will display the green check mark with the warning that says "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" as described [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/07/18/excel-convert-text-to-number/).

Comment: See [here](https://imgur.com/a/Gv2eEpP) (code ran without pre-formatted cells). Both options format to text with the excel warning tip that it's a number formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe. Not sure what causes your excel to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

According to the most recent Microsoft docs, VBA Round function can indeed return different results from the Application.WorksheetFunction.Round method. Here is how Microsoft explains this in the [docs for Round function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function):

> This VBA function returns something commonly referred to as bankers
> rounding. So be careful before using this function. For more
> predictable results, use Worksheet Round functions in Excel VBA.

Here's an example of how peculiar VBA Round function rounding results can be even if all the numeric values are set to Double:

Here's a piece of code where all the numeric values are in Double format:

```
WeightNetto = rngArticleCell.Offset(, 8).Value2
Quantity23 = rngArticleCell.Offset(, -4).Value2
If Quantity23 <> 0 Then
    WeightPerUnit = WeightNetto / Quantity23
    RndWeightPerUnit = Round(WeightPerUnit, 3)
Else
   WeightPerUnit = 0
End If
```

**Rounding case #1:**
[image: Rounding case #1]

**Rounding case #2:**
[image: Rounding case #2]

As you can see, in case #2 above VBA Round keeps rounding the half down to 2. However, if you run case #2 through Application.WorksheetFunction.Round the half will be rounded up to 3.

Therefore if you really need your VBA code to achieve exact rounding results to the in-cell Round() function, I strongly encourage you to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Round instead of the actual VBA Round.